# Where can I download the 64-bit Travis-CI VM images?

Tags: github, travis-ci

These two [blog](http://ruby-journal.com/debug-your-failed-test-in-travis-ci/) [posts](http://reidburke.com/2013/01/28/debugging-travis-builds/) describe a way to debug failing regression tests using the same VM image that Travis-CI uses.  It's a great idea, but the download link given there is out-of-date: the `.box` files they link to are **32-bit** images, and Travis-CI now uses **64-bit** images.

Where can I download the 64-bit images that Travis-CI now uses?

**Update:** Just in case it's useful: These days I use [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) for continuous integration, which offers easy-to-use ssh access to the build container.  That makes debugging a troublesome CI setup **way** easier.  Now there's no need to replicate the CI environment locally, as I was trying to do when I originally submitted this question.

Comment: Have a look at the UserGroup channel: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/travis-ci/d1iANFN2_iI

Answer (score 9):

We are no longer using Vagrant for our backend, and as such we aren't maintaining the Vagrant images. We're looking into a way of doing this, but for now you can email us at support AT travis-ci.org and we can spin up a debug VM for you if you need to debug an issue.

Comment: Hi, can you let us know what you use for the backend now for Travis?  I would have loved to have a Vagrant image of Travis for testing my stuff so I don't have to keep pushing commits.  Emailing you individually doesn't seem like a scaleable solution for anyone who wants to debug.  Thanks Henrik.