# How to run Travis-CI's trusty distribution locally

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to migrate from the container based infrastructure due to the Arduino alike performance. Travis' support suggested I use the "new" trusty dist based on Ubuntu 14.04 but I am having lot of trouble with it.

Is there an easy way to debug their base image locally?

Comment: sounds a reasonable question to ask, care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the current workflow to debug Travis builds locally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544803/what-is-the-current-workflow-to-debug-travis-builds-locally)

Comment: @tellisnz my question was specific to one of the 3 different infrastructures Travis supports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you use the minimal trusty image, you are pretty much using plain Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) and you don't have most of the nice stuff that is bundled with other distributions.

Since you are not going to use most of Travis cookbooks, the simplest way to come up with a good `.travis.yml` manifest is install Ubuntu Trusty on a VM and try every single setup command there.